# max width doesn't work in html

Tags: html, css

Below is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/RHM5L/

```
<div id="resultwrap">  
    <div id="wholenum"><div id="wholenumres">44444444444444444</div></div> 
    <div id="numer"><div id="numerres"></div>44444444444444444444444</div>
    <div id="denom"><div id="denomres"></div>44444444444444444444444</div>
</div>
```

It is a fraction. Whole number should be at the left part and numerator and denominator at the right part.
but when the numerator and denominator have too much of text it won't overflow:hidden but will go down.

How should i have it fixed there ?

Comment: What exactly do you want? see this once and tell me http://jsfiddle.net/RHM5L/1/

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You speak of max width, don't provide any code and in your fiddle you declared max-height...

Comment: i think the text in ID `numerres` and `denomres` are not in that div element. try replace your HTML above with this `<div id="resultwrap">  
    <div id="wholenum"><div id="wholenumres">44444444444444444</div></div> 
    <div id="numer"><div id="numerres">44444444444444444444444</div></div>
    <div id="denom"><div id="denomres">44444444444444444444444</div></div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to float 
HTML :

```
<div id="resultwrap">
    <div id="wholenum">whole number value</div>
</div id="tow">
    <div id="numerator">dino</div>
    <div id="denominator">some value is hererss</div>    
</div>

CSS:
#wholenum{
        overflow:hidden;
        height:40px;  
        float:left;
    }
    #tow{
        float:left;
        height:40px;
        max-height:120px;


    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RHM5L/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted max-width but in your jsfiddle you only have max-height:

change your code to this:

```
#resultwrap{
    max-width:120px; <!-- max-width --> 
    height:120px;
    background:blue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHM5L/19/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="resultwrap">  
    <div id="wholenumres">wholenumres : 44444444444444444</div>
    <div class="numeranddenom">
       <div id="numerres">numerres : 444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444</div>
       <div id="denom">denom : 44444444444444444444444</div>
    <div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#resultwrap{
    width: 320px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.44);
    word-break: break-word;        
}

#wholenumres {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 49%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.numeranddenom {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 49%;
}
```